# Upgrading Guest operating system on VMWare image

Tags: vmware-server

We have a VMWare Server host, with around 3-4 virtualised machines on.

Currently, 2 of them are running on Windows 2000
I want to upgrade them (in place upgrade) to Windows 2003
Is this possible?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Jim - was my answer good, or do you have other requirements or concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you would do it for physical machines. Slot the 2003 CD or ISO and run the installer to do the upgrade.

Comment: I normally upload the CD ISO and mount it virtually rather than use the physical CD, but that's just me.

Comment: And, of course, back up the current VM image that's running fine, just in case something goes wrong with the upgrade. I know you can snapshot it and roll it back but I normally copy the VM and compress it somewhere. Others may have in-place backup software (as if it were a physical machine) that can restore the VM from "virtual bare metal". Whatever you do, make sure you have a backup to recover from.